# Watir won't select / find the link element

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I've came to this problem for quite a few times now.

It appears that Watir won't find the anchor (link) element, when I want to find it by the following syntax:

```
@browser.link(:text => 'View page directly').click
```

If I try checking link presence it will say that it doesn't exist, although the link is there.

Here is the link to original source code that causes this behavior:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3290107/watir-test.xhtml

Why is this happening and how to fix it?

Thanks for help

Comment: I think the problem might be the .xhtml extension. The page seems to work just fine when saved as .htm, but when saved as .xhtml has the problem you see.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug to me. You should report it here: https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/issues

```
browser.a(:text => "View page directly").present?
# => false 

browser.as[-2].text
# => "View page directly" 

browser.as[-2].present?
# => true
```